# Description Resource Path Location Type 'UINT16_MAX' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compilation, armv7

I want to create a .so librairy in UUDO card running lubuntu with armvl7 processor , i have a source code and i compiled it but he give me the error in one of my files .cpp Description Resource Path Location Type 'UINT16_MAX' was not declared in this scope I had included  but dosn't work and still the same, also i verified that stdint.h exist in /usr/include/ so really i don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i was missing is:

```
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

this macro is mandatory in order to run and compile right